# Custom properties in Maven based on command line switch

Tags: maven-2, maven

*[reduced for simplicity]*

I have a project with several Maven modules

A module has a properties files whose contents are filtered during build

There are sets of properties that can be grouped

Only one group of properties exists in a given build

All groups have the same properties, only their values change between groups

```
parent
+- pom.xml
+- foo
   +- src/main/resources/test.properties
```

I have set profiles in parent `pom.xml`. Each profile is activated by a command line argument and sets the values for the properties on that group.

```
mvn clean compile -Dgroup1=true
```

The problem is that I have to duplicate the entire profile between groups. I would like to only define the `<properties>` for each of the groups and use a single profile to control build order, plugins and other stuff.

Anyone knows if that can be done?

Answer (score 2):

That sounds to me like you want to just create a different set of property files for every profile, something like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>group1</id>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>src/main/resources/propertyfile1.txt</filter>
                <filter>src/main/resources/propertyfile2.txt</filter>
            </filters>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>group2</id>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>src/main/resources/propertyfile3.txt</filter>
                <filter>src/main/resources/propertyfile4.txt</filter>
            </filters>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now each profile gives you different values in resource filtering.

---

If you also need the values in the pom, you will have to do some more processing, probably using the [maven properties plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) or something similar. Put the meat of the plugin definition in the main build element:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And configure the loaded files in the individual profiles:

```
<profile>
    <id>group1</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <files>
                        <file>src/main/resources/propertyfile1.txt</file>
                        <file>src/main/resources/propertyfile2.txt</file>
                    </files>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be accomplished by using `<pluginManagement>`. You would declare build order, plugins and other stuff in the parent pom within `<pluginManagement>` section and then in each child, you would soecify the `<plugin>` along with the appropriate `properties`.